# UITableView scrolling odd behaviour

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableViewController in my app (well several but this only happens on this particular one).

The content is driven from Core Data using an NSFetchedResultsController and the TVC is a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and uses the methods for updating the table based on content changes (i.e. it runs the beginUpdates, endUpdates etc...).

I've done this a number of times before and so just use the same code.  (Also can be found on Ray Wenderlich's site).

Anyway, I have a view (pushed from the TVC) that adds new items in to the CoreData DB.  This new item should then be added into the TVC's table.

This is all working fine.  I view the Table scroll up and down it fine. Click add. Add the new item.  Push back to the TableView and I can see the new item...

BUT

The tableView doesn't allow me to scroll all the way to the bottom now.  I can see the new data in the table by scrolling to the bottom and holding the screen but when I let go the tableView bounces back so that I can no longer see it.

I have checked several things...

1. The frame of the TableView is unchanged before and after.
2. The contentSize of the tableView DOES change to accommodate the added cells.
3. When scrolling the minimum contentOffset is 0 both before and after (this is correct).
4. When scrolling the MAXIMUM contentOffset is the same both before and after (this is not correct).

If I pop back to the rootVC and then push back to the TVC then I can scroll all the way again and see all my new cells.

I did some testing.

If I re-enable autoRotating using `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` then go through the motions of adding the new cells etc then I still can't scroll to the bottom.  But if I rotate landscape and then back to portrait then now I can scroll all the way to the bottom.

Off the back of this I tried running the `[self viewWillLayoutSubViews];` method after the `[self.tableView endUpdates];` but still nothing.

Like I said, I have done this before many times and with no problems.  I really don't understand what is happening now.

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubViews` is a notification method, to request layout you'll want to use view's `setNeedsLayout`, I'd also check if `autoresizesSubviews` is set to YES for the tableView.

Comment: Ah, I'm not subclassing any views or anything just the TableViewController.  setNeedsLayout would be on the UITableView.

Comment: Yes, please try [self.tableView setNeedsLayout], this should help as the rotation helps. I don't know the reason to fix the exact problem source though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't sorted it either :( I tried putting the [self.tableView setNeedsLayout] in the viewWillAppear and also after the endUpdates but neither has sorted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that worked!

In the end I had to put `[self.tableView reloadData];` into the `viewDidAppear` method.

That solved the problem.